# how can I convert System.Drawing.Icon to System.Drawing.Image?

Tags: c#, .net, image, icons, system.drawing

I'm getting icon from another application using this:

```
Icon IEIcon =  Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
```

how to convert it to [System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.image.aspx)?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

#### Description

The `Bitmap` is derived from `Image` so you can use Icon's `.ToBitmap()` method.

#### Sample

```
Icon IEIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
Image im = IEIcon.ToBitmap();
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Bitmap Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx)
- [MSDN - Image Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx)

Comment: I didn't knew that this `cast` it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: +1 @TheMask - Thanks, I knew that  a million years ago - saved me a bit of work toady!

Answer (score 11):

Could you use the `ToBitmap()` method.

[ToBitmap()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.tobitmap.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

For who wants to do the inverse: (VB.NET; myImage-> myIcon)

```
Dim tmpBmp As Bitmap
tmpBmp = myImage
Dim hIcon As IntPtr = tmpBmp.GetHicon
myIcon = Icon.FromHandle(hIcon)
```

I'm writing this here beacause by googling "*System.Drawing.Image' converted to 'System.Drawing.Icon*" brings here and I think it does not deserve a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Original at : [Convert Icon to Image in C#](http://coders-project.blogspot.com/2008/04/convert-icon-to-image-in-c.html)

```
Icon a =  Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");

Image im = a.ToBitmap()
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple.  Icon has a method named `ToBitmap`.

```
Image converted_image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe").ToBitmap()
```